# Win7 Mounting network drives depending on network

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, mount, home-networking, samba

Is there a way of mounting certain drives with NET USE only when you're connected to certain networks?  I use this particular laptop at home and at work.  When I am at home and connect to the network there, I'd like to automatically mount some samba shares that are present.

At the moment I use the /persistent flag.  If one of the home shares gets selected by accident  or a program attempts to scan it whilst I am at work, Explorer tends to hang.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do that with Scheduled Tasks in Windows 7.  It has triggers for startup / login and can run jobs only if networks are available (Conditions-> Start only if the following network connection is available).  Create a script with `net use` and have the Task Manager run it when the conditions are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NetProfiles](http://code.google.com/p/netprofiles/) who can easily do the mount itself.
However you'll need to choose which profile to run on any of the networks you connect